# Change date format (Javascript / Angular )

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm getting a date from a service but it seems this is not really a date format.

I tried to print like:

{{vm.NapIncident.RecordDate | date: 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy'}}

But it's printing

**2018-10-11+01:00 on the frontend.**

Is there a way to show the record date in the format that I want?

Comment: I tried your code (date format) and it displays as what you want. There must be something else that is causing the issue in your environment. Maybe caching? Try https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic

Comment: What is `vm.NapIncident.RecordDate`? String? Date object? Can you create working snippet (icon `[<>]` in editor) to demonstrate your issue? Are you using angular (like in title) or angularjs (like in tag)?

Comment: I assume that `vm.NapIncident.RecordDate` is a string. How can I do this if that is a string? Filtering doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

try moment.js

```
moment().format("h:mm:ss a,Do MMMM YYYY,");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Use moment js. For more advance level you can make filter for dateformat and use code as  below.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.filter')
    .filter('utcDate', utcDate);

function utcDate() {
    return function (value, format) {
        moment.locale("en");
        switch (format) {
            case 'shortTime':
                format = 'LT';
                break;
            case 'shortDate':
                format = 'L';
                break;
            case 'communityDate':
                format = 'LT L';
                break;
            case 'orderDate':
                format = 'LT ll';
                break;
            case 'orderLongTime':
                format = 'HH:mm';
                break;
            case 'activityDate':
                format = 'L LT';
                break;
            case 'chatComivo':
                format = 'MMM D';
                break;
            case 'broadcastReplyTime':
                format = 'HH:mm a';
                break;
            case 'broadcastReplyDate':
                format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
                break;
            case 'promotionDate':
                format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
                break;
            case 'converstionDate':
                format = 'MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss a';
                break;
            case 'lastRead':
                format = 'lll';
                break;
             case 'test':
                format = 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy';

        }

        //var localDate = moment.utc(value).local(); this is for to convert date into utc date
        //return localDate.format(format);return moment().format(format); 

return    moment().format(format)     }    }})();
```

And use following html

```
this date <p>{{date | utcDate:'test'}}</p>
```

you can update it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the date in this format "dd/mm/yyyy". You can use regex to convert the date.

```
 this.NapIncident.recordDate = new Date(this.NapIncident.recordDate.replace(/(\d{2})- 
(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))
 }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-s47m4h?file=home%2Fhome.html)